# how to create a group of radio buttons with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why this simple program doesn't work?
It's a program that creates a group of radio buttons with Javascript.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function onWriteRadio(Valuse,numButtons,RadioName){
        for(i=0;i<numButtons;i++){
          document.write("<input type='radio' name=" + RadioName + "value="       +Valuse[i]+"/>");
          document.write("<br/>");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="onWriteRadio([red,green,blue],3,'color')>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

use this:

```
onWriteRadio(['red','green','blue'],3,'color')
```

string the array values. Currently, you say [red,green,blue], that means the variable red, variable green, variable blue, BUT you don't define them anywhere, so your program is saying "hmm, i do not know what red is.".. so string em.

Answer (score 2):

put array values in quotes

```
onWriteRadio(['red','green','blue'],3,'color')
```

Answer (score 1):

you left some quotation marks.

```js
function onWriteRadio(values, radioName){
    
          for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        document.write("<input type='radio' name='" + radioName + "' value='" +values[i]+"' >"+values[i]+" </ input>");
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="onWriteRadio(['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'color')">

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document, which replaes your earlier `html` content.

`document.write()` executed after the page has finished loading will overwrite the page, or write a new page.

`document.write()` is a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

1. place array values in quotes
2. add closing double quote for **onload**
3. make one string containing all inputs code and then write it

Your code should look smthng like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onWriteRadio(Valuse,numButtons,RadioName){
    var s = '';
    for(i=0;i<numButtons;i++){
        s += "<input type='radio' name=" + RadioName + "value="       +Valuse[i]+"/>"
    }
    document.write(s);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onWriteRadio(['red','green','blue'],3,'color')">
</body>
</html>
```